# Which package includes calendar and time at the top in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: gnome-shell, system-tray

There's a bug I'd like to report but i don't know which package the calendar at the top tray belongs to. Gnome-shell or system-tray? The version is Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 22.10. Calendar at the top gets bugged when you click a date from the next month. Restart solves it but when i open any app it happens again.

Comment: A good idea is to edit the question and add the version info. You can report this bug. Here is the site to report it. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: Already did. Thx for  the advice regardless. Bug #1994031